# A specific layout of repeating data required

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datarepeater

I want to show database data along these lines:

```
[row 1 col 1]   [row 1 col 3]
[row 1 col 2]   [row 1 col 4]

[row 2 col 1]   [row 2 col 3]
[row 2 col 2]   [row 2 col 4]

[row 3 col 1]   [row 3 col 3]
[row 3 col 2]   [row 3 col 4]

Etc
```

Can something like the gridview or repeater controls do this easily or would I have to create custom controls and use them?

Thanks

Comment: `Repeater` control will do this easily for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use **Repeater** to do that.

**ASPX**

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"col1") %>   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"col3") %>
            <br>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"col2") %>   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"col4") %>
            <br>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</form>
```

**C#**

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("yourconnection");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from yourtable", cnn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Temp");
Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Temp"];
Repeater1.DataBind();
```